# c# program to call Google+ API and Custom Search API from Google

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-api

Can you please tell me via a code sample how I can write a C# program that will call
the Google+ API and Custom Search API of Google.

I know there is a brief description of it on  :::::

> URL:https://developers.google.com/+/api/
>   URL:https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest
>   URL:http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2

But the process mentioned in the links in doing the above as given in the documentation is
not very clear.
Is there a simple illustration through C# code that I can use to call Google+ API and Custom
Search API?

Answer (score 0):

The [Google API Dotnet Client project](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) contains .NET wrappers form most of Google's APIs, [including Google+](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Google+_API).

They do have [several examples](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/GettingStarted) but not for all of their APIs, yet.

A Google+ example from their page to query for public activities is:

```
CommandLine.EnableExceptionHandling();            
CommandLine.DisplayGoogleSampleHeader("PlusService API");     

// Create the service.             
var objService= new PlusService();
objService.Key = ""; //put in user key.

var acts = objService.Activities.Search();
acts.Query = "super cool";
acts.MaxResults = 10;

var searchResults = acts.Fetch();

if (searchResults.Items != null)
{
   foreach (Activity feed in searchResults.Items)
   {
      //extract any property of uer interest
      CommandLine.WriteResult(feed.Title, feed.Actor);
   }
}
```